Electrical analysis using nodal voltage method
I had a exercise which made me confused for a day and couldn't find out the solution by using nodal voltage method. If I used mesh current method, I figured out u1 = E = 373V.
How would I work it out using the nodal method?


Choosing node B as GND would be a good choice since you have to calculate $v_1$. You have chosen the GND anyway. It may not matter where the GND is as long as it has connections to maximum number of branches. With mesh analysis, the problem may be a little easier.

@AmitM but the dependent current source makes me a little bit difficult.

See this post which is similar to your question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36774/applying-nodal-inspection-technique-to-supernodes-with-dependent-sources  It may have a method for using a supernode..

With your ground node, you have to use two super nodes. This is not efficient and a bit cumbersome. Choose Ground at the bottom of the circuit.Currents and voltages wont vary based on choice of ground.
I'm not really sure if this method works as this problem is a bit tricky. Form a super node around the dependent voltage source \$3i_2\$ . Let voltages at nodes A and C be \$V_A\$ and \$V_C\$. Let voltage at the middle node above 2ohm resistor and to the left of another 2 ohm resistor be \$V_B\$. Make the node which is written as B as GND.
See the modified circuit diagram below.

Using nodal analysis and KVL,
$$v_1 =  V_B$$
$$ \frac {V_A- 373 }{1} + \frac {V_B- 0}{2} + \frac {V_B- V_C}{2}= 2 (V_B) $$
$$ \frac {V_C}{4} + \frac {V_C- V_B }{2} = -2(V_B)  $$
$$V_A- V_B = 3i_2 $$
$$373- V_A = i_2 $$
Solve for \$V_A, V_B , V_C\$ and with those calculate \$i_1, i_2, i_3 \$ and \$i_4\$

I got it, thank you very much.

For KCL (nodal) you only have two unknown node voltages, \$v_b\$ and \$v_c\$. So that's only two KCL equations.
The rest is defined. You know for a fact that \$v_a=3i_2\$, so no need for KCL on that node. And you know that \$i_2=\frac{v_b+373\:\text{V}-v_a}{1\:\Omega}=\frac{v_b+373\:\text{V}-3i_2}{1\:\Omega}\$, so \$i_2=\frac14\left(v_b+373\right)\$ and \$i_2\$ is proven to be entirely defined by \$v_b\$.
\$v_b\$ KCL is \$\frac{v_b}{4\:\Omega}+\frac{v_b}{2\:\Omega}+i_2=\frac{v_c}{4\:\Omega}\$ . Replacing \$i_2\$, then: \$\frac{v_b}{4\:\Omega}+\frac{v_b}{2\:\Omega}+\frac14\left(v_b+373\right)=\frac{v_c}{4\:\Omega}\$.
\$v_c\$ KCL is \$\frac{v_c}{4\:\Omega}+\frac{v_c}{2\:\Omega}-2v_b=\frac{v_b}{4\:\Omega}\$.
